# Best tool for Analyzing IIS 7 SMTP Logs

Tags: smtp, logging, analysis

We're using IIS 7's SMTP service for sending out emails from our sites. I'm looking for a SMTP Log analyzer to make it easier for me to view the results and identify and problems (Blocks, Unauthorized relay attempts, blacklisting, ...).

What is the best tool to use for this?

Answer (score 1):

logparser is the tool of choice! http://www.microsoft.com/downloads then search for logparser.  then go here http://forums.iis.net/default.aspx?GroupID=51

also http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/forensic-log-parsing-microsofts-logparser